# Extract Tar file

Tags: 12.04

I am not able to extract tar file 
Command 
tar -xvfz node_archive.tar.gz khem

Error

show error tar:z: can't open :No such file or directory
tar: Error is not recoverable : Exiting now

Comment: use ls to see the name and then try it as "tar xvf name,tar,gz"

Comment: try removing  khem from your command

Comment: try gzrecover if it is corrupted

Comment: duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/q/25961/192102

Comment: -xvfz tells tar to open a file named 'z'.  Use -xvzf instead.

Answer (score 1):

Run the following commands on terminal,

```
cd /path/to/the/directory/which/contains/node_archive.tar.gz
tar -xzvf node_archive.tar.gz
```